# Codeigniter and Bootstrap Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I'm using **Bootstrap** and **Codeigniter**, my question is about dropdown menu. 
In homepage it fits perfectly, but after I use a controller to call a page, it doesn't work anymore.(sometimes I need it to get some data from database)

[When it's working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2DGJ.png)
[When it's doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CyzS.png)
here is dropdown in HTML

```html
<li class='nav-item dropdown'>
                <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href="" role='button' id="dropdownCadastro"
                   data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Projeto
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu shadow border-0" aria-labelledby="dropdownCadastro">
                <a class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger" href='<?php echo base_url('projeto');?> '>Cadastrar Projeto</a>
               <a class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger" href='<?php echo base_url('avaliacao');?> '>Avaliar Projeto</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger" href='<?php echo base_url('consultarProjetoServidor');?> '>Consultar Projeto</a>
                </div>
            </li>
```

header

```html
  <link  rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" >
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('fonts/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css') ?>" >
    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/one-page-wonder.min.css') ?>" >
```

footer

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You mean in HOME page the layout works fine but if you access some other page it breaks? If so, my guess is that you might have missed closing tag of an element or something in the HTML part. Just a guess. See if that's the issue.

Comment: I break if in URL i have controller name.
eg.: url/controller/dropdownTarget (break)
url/dropdownTarget (Work)

Comment: _but after I use a controller to call a page_, how do you call the dropdown view from that controller?

Comment: I call with a sidebar like in href='<?php echo base_url('projeto');?>